# Is it possible to add to class extension method via attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, attributes

Say I have a simple class tree:

```
public class Operation {
    public int callback;
}

public class OperationResponse : Operation {
}
```

Now I would love to add a new class `OperationRequest` that would have a simple Extension method like:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetResponse<T>(this Operation source) where T : Operation {
        return new T{ callback = source.callback };
    } 
}
```

I would love to define it with something like:

```
[Response(OperationResponse)]
public class OperationRequest {
}
```

And have its Extension be specified as `GetResponse<OperationResponse>`. Is such thing possible with attributes in .net4 and how to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you're driving at. _If_ C# supported it, what are you trying to do? What is the expected code/usage of this attribute or `OperationRequest` at this point? How would you want to call `GetResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can have such of some sort though a complicated structure at run time. But it is impossible to have design time intellisense that extension could provide.
Attribute is more of run time behavior.